# Search For String In File Using Variables

Tags: powershell, logfile

Having some trouble searching a log file. I have a basic script that searches for specific text in a log file. The problem is, I am trying to use variables that can be adjusted by the user at the command line but I cannot get them to be recognized. The script should output the results back to the screen.

```
param (
[string]$file ,
[string]$Ip ,
[string]$port
)
Get-Content -Path C:\$file | Where-Object {$_ -like $Ip -and $_ -like $port}
```

Example of command line to execute script:

`PS C:\> .\LogSearch.ps1 logfile04.txt 192.168.1.7 21`

In this case, `logfile04.txt` is the file, the port is `21` and the IP address is `192.168.1.7`

At this point of running the script, I am returned with nothing, but there is that line within the file.

`4|Oct 19 2015|18:28:39|106023|75.76.77.80|50077|192.168.1.7|21|Deny tcp src`

Comment: `-like` uses regex. If you type the IP and port surrounded in `*`, does it work?

Comment: @MacroPower `-like` does not use regex that would be `-match`. [`-like` uses wildcards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Wildcards) of which `*` is indeed one.

Comment: Using the `*` in the command line does work! I am now getting all of the lines with `192.168.1.7` instead of just the ones with port `21`. But I guess that is a different problem not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-like` operator when used without a wildcard is the equivalent of `-eq`. Since your line doesn't both exactly equal `192.168.1.7` and `21` at the same time, it will never return. So if you wanted to use `-like` you will need to surround your match string with wildcards.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\$file | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$Ip*" -and $_ -like "*$port*"}
```

Alternatively, the `-match` operator uses regex. So you wouldn't need the wildcards.

```
Get-Content -Path C:\$file | Where-Object {$_ -match $Ip -and $_ -match $port}
```

Here is a [good guide on the different uses of these comparison operators](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/powershell-operators-like-match)